# Passing dynamic value to url using retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit

I am trying to make a simple weather app using retrofit library. I want the city name to be dynamic. This is what i have done so far:

full url:

```
    http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=dhaka&cnt=7&appid=1111
```

base url:

```
    http://api.openweathermap.org/
```

in the main activity

```
    LinkedHashMap<String,String>data=new LinkedHashMap<>();
    data.put("q",targetCity);
    data.put("cnt",Integer.toString(7));
    data.put("appid",getString(R.string.api_key));
    Call<WeatherResponse>weatherResponseCall=weatherServiceApi.getAllWeatherReport(data);
```

and in my api interface:

```
    @GET("data/2.5/forecast/daily?")
Call<WeatherResponse>getAllWeatherReport(@QueryMap LinkedHashMap<String,String>data);
```

I am neither getting any error, nor any response data.
Please help.

Comment: Can you accept my answer if it helps you? thx :)

Answer (score 0):

You aren't executing the call function...

```
WeatherResponse response = call.execute().body();
```

If I were you, I would try using a `ResponseBody` from **okhttp** to get the data returned. Then using `response.string()` you can see what's retrieved from the request.

Or, to log the body data of each **request/response** you should add this interceptor when building your Retrofit object:

```
OkHttpClient client = httpClient.addInterceptor(interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY))
        .build();
Retrofit retrofit = builder.client(client).build();
return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
```